# Is there a way to open *.pbxproj files with eclipse?

Tags: java, xcode, eclipse, classpath, project

I'm looking (if it exists) a way to import few XCode java projects into eclipse, maybe a plugin or something that starting from a `pbxproj file`, generates an eclipse project `(.classpath + .project)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many searches on the internet I reached this URI:
[Migrating from XCode to eclipse](http://www.global-village.net/migrate.to.eclipse/basic_migration).

There you can read this:

> Migrating with a script is pretty easy and it is not a complex script, it just copies files and puts Java classes into the package structure. The script does not do everything, it just takes the drudgery out of it.  You will want to convert all the frameworks before the applications as the applications will need the frameworks to build.
>
> The first step is to create a new Eclipse project, a Wonder Application or a Wonder Framework, and give it the same name as the Xcode project. This does NOT mean you will be using Project Wonder, it just refers to a project layout developed for Wonder.
>
> cd into your Xcode project, Run ./fleeto /path/to/eclipse/project, Refresh the project in Eclipse (select and press F5 or use the context menu), Repeat for other frameworks and applications.
>
> For working in Eclipse you will want to have the framework projects included as required projects in the applications and frameworks that use them.  For each project, Properties - Java Build Path is the central place to manage your project. Select the Projects tab and add the framework projects that this application references.
>
> These project dependencies work in Eclipse but not for deployment.  For deployment you need to reference frameworks from their installed location. Install the framework (see Install on the context menu).
>
> Then go to the Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries tab and configure the WO Frameworks library. Expand the nodes and select the installed framework(s).
>
> REMOVE the checkmarks beside the ERJars and ERExtensions framework if you are not using Project Wonder. Finally, adjust the order on the Order and Export tab so that required projects appear before the WO Frameworks Library. Doing this ensures that Eclipse uses the current code and not a previously installed version.